# The best way to find intersection two std::vectors of 3D points

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, std

I was wondering if there is a way, using standard library, to find an intersection of two vectors of 3D points. 3D point is a glm::vec3 with x, y and z.
x, y and z are floats.

I know that we can use a std::set_intersection on 1D arrays.

Just to be clear I have 2 vectors:

```
std::vector<Point> v1;
std::vector<Point> v2;
```

where Point is:

```
struct Point {
    glm::vec3 m_position;
    glm::vec2 m_texCoord;
    glm::vec3 m_normal;

    Point() {}

    Point(glm::vec3& pos, glm::vec2& tex, glm::vec3& norm) {
        m_position = pos;
        m_normal = norm;
        m_texCoord = tex;
    }

    Point(glm::vec3& pos, glm::vec3& norm) {
        m_position = pos;
        m_normal = norm;
    }

    Point(glm::vec3& pos) {
        m_position = pos;
    }
};
```

I would like to find an intersection of v1 and v2 by Point.m_position.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you define intersection, if you mean standard set theoretical intersection? If so can you define the sets which are the operand to be intersected? Also so point is an array of points, themselves arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation of [`std::set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) it's mentioned that

> 1) Elements are compared using operator< and the ranges must be sorted with respect to the same.

So basically you need to provide an overloaded `operator<()` for `Point`, and sort those vectors before calling `std::set_intersection()`.

Comment: Would you please elaborate how would I write {operator<()} to sort point in 3D?

Comment: @Illia I'm afraid that's your job regarding the `glm` domain knowledge you have. I don't have any.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I have followed your advance and it seems to work fine. I don't know if there is a way to sort point in 3D but I figured if I apply "my" sorting function and it is deterministic and the same a across all the points it should still work. I am in the process of testing it right now. It is a little time consuming but I think it should work.